# Youtube API Error - Authentication

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

I'm newbie in Youtube API and I trying upload a video by NodeJS, but is returning this error.

```
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
  <error>
    <domain>GData</domain>
    <code>ServiceForbiddenException</code>
    <internalReason>Currently authenticated user does not have write access to username: "marlos"'s videos.</internalReason>
  </error>
 </errors>
```

What I have do for resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to handle uploads is to use the username "default" when constructing your upload URL, as described at

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading

This will ensure that the upload goes into the account associated with the current authorization token.

There's sample code to do this using the .NET client library available at

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet#Direct_Upload